# files().update(...).execute() method returns "400 Bad Request" only in the case of double-byte character user name

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am using `Google Drive SDK` for Java.

Since 27th or 28th June, `Drive.files().update(...).execute()` returns `400 Bad Request` only in the case of the user name of google account is `double-byte` character like a Kanji(Japanese character).

But `Drive.files().insert(...).execute()` is working fine.

And in the case of the user name of google account is ASCII character, update and insert are working fine.

Is there any bug in `Google Drive API Service`?
Or something wrong with my code?

Following is the StackTrace of the Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
Bad Request
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at drivetest.Sample.main(Sample.java:71)
```

Code

```
package drivetest;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.ByteArrayContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

public class Sample {
    private static String CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID";
    private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET";

    private static String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                .setAccessType("online")
                .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

        String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
        System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
        System.out.println("  " + url);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String code = br.readLine();

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

        // Create a new authorized API client
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

        // Insert a file
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle("Mydocument");
        body.setDescription("A test document");
        body.setMimeType("text/plain");

        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

        String text = "update!";
        ByteArrayContent overwrite = new ByteArrayContent("text/plain", text.getBytes());

        File over = service.files().update(file.getId(), file, overwrite).execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + over.getId());
    }
}
```

POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev82-1.15.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I created some accounts with Japanese names such as 高鍋進 and tried to reproduce your error but couldn't. If you could provide exact procedure to reproduce your error step by step, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You will reproduce it just run the above code.I created an accounts with Japanese name 高鍋進 and run the above code, then I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have met this problem too, I think it maybe a bug. After my testing, I found when I create a new file to pass into update() method's second parameter, it works fine again, you can try it, good luck!

```
File newFile = new File().setTitle(file.getTitle()).setMimeType(file.getMimeType()).setParents(file.getParents());
Files.Update updateOperation = mDriveService.files().update(file.getId(), newFile, fileContent);
```

Comment: I tried your solution and then my code works fine. Thank you!